# Extracting from text using tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, text-extraction

I have the following string format in a Sql table column

`[CID]: 267 [MID]: 319A [Name]: RJR`

How can I extract only the value of MID which is 319A in select query so I can use the MID in a join.
In other words I need to extract the MID value from this text field to use it in a join. I copy/pasted the value and it looks like there are /n (new line) characters after each value.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have to create stored function wich gets you string as parameter and returns MID value as result

Comment: other rows are the same but with different values. 319A can be DS324A or 32456A or 31

Comment: SQL string function are weak. And if MID or NAME are not present then it may send an invalid number to substring and your query fails (like error no more rows process). I would consider going Regex as suggested by Xeno.

Comment: When you store this data in the database, why don't you split it apart instead of storing it together? Obviously there is some embedded data in this string that is relevant and important on its own. Why do you want to bury it as a portion of another string?

Comment: The data exists. I cannot change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this one.

```
declare 

    @t varchar(100)
    set @t = '[CID]: 267 [MID]: 319A [Name]: RJR';
    select ltrim(rtrim(substring(@t,charindex('[MID]:',@t)+6,(charindex('[NAME]',@t))-(charindex('[MID]:',@t)+6))))
---------------------------------------------------------
319A
```

ltrim and rtrim will trim your `319A` value. 
you can try without them at start if you like.

---

Cheers

Comment: I like this but it says invalid column values [MID]: and [Name]:

Comment: my bad single quotes instead of double quotes. i've edited answer

Comment: yup figured... I've updated the shift of the index for both `charindex` functions.

Comment: Now I have 319A followed by [Name....
I will have to say get the value before [Name

Comment: It's alright I'm just being dumb. substring's last parameter is the size to be taken so we substract the index of the [mid] from the index of the [name] and it should be your size of the value to trim.

Comment: I'm getting  the following err
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Severity 16 State 4

Comment: just an update my real [MID]: has 12 characters so I changed the 6 to 12 in my query

Comment: In other words it something like this: [MyID00022]:

Comment: no need to manipulate your string. it's fixed. just try it now and put instead of `@t` your column and add `from yourtable` of course

Comment: select ltrim(rtrim(substring(BatchData,charindex('[MyID00022]:',BatchData)+12,
    (charindex('[Name0000001]:',BatchData))-(charindex('[MyID00022]:',BatchData)+12))))
from myTable

Comment: This displays the correct value but then throws the following err:
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Severity 16 State 4

Comment: keep in mind that, 319A value might change. To 319 or 319304 for example

Comment: probably you have some rows which do not conform to this description that being said that there're probably no [MID] or [NAME] tags present or they are present but in different order that's why it fails you should cleanup your rows perhaps. it works for sure.

Comment: regex requires installation of clr. not everyone is fond of installing extra stuff on prod servers...

Comment: @SergeyBenner I agree on the clr is not for everyone.  I meant to comment on the main as I did not mean to detract from your answer.  +1

Comment: @sev length of what? of `[MID]:` tag it's exactly 6 characters ??? if the length of your tags changes then it will be hard to determine the start index of your search string. you have to have some start and end points of your search string otherwise there's no good way to determine it without regexps

Comment: Ok I found the issue. The problem is in some of my rows the [Name]: is missing which is not good news. That was resulting in a minus charindex

Comment: @Sev See my comment to your question.  "And if MID or NAME are not present then it may send an invalid number to substring and your query fails (like error no more rows process)."

Answer (score 1):

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/tsql-regular-expression-workbench/

to add regex support to sql server

[Rubular Regex](http://rubular.com/r/CM40pl7165) to get you started:

```
\[MID\]: (.*) \[Name]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clean at ALL, but if you need it in SQL, here you go:

Use

```
SUBSTRING ( value_expression , start_expression , length_expression )
```

and

```
 LOCATE( string1, string2 [, start] )
```

together:

```
SUBSTRING(INPUT, 
         ((SELECT LOCATE( 'MID]: ', INPUT ))+6),
         ((SELECT LOCATE( '[Name]', INPUT )) - ((SELECT LOCATE( 'MID]: ', INPUT ))+6))
```

depending where is taking place? If it is in a batch process, I would export those fields with an ID, write a perl one liner that extracts them, and then load them back to the db. it would be so much faster than using these functions.

if it is screen event, then I suggest breaking them into 3 columns instead, itll actully save you space.

Comment: that 319A is a dynamic value. it can be 232394AAdd

Comment: @Jordan what dialect uses `LOCATE`? I couldn't get this to work in SQL Server. (`'LOCATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.`)

Comment: @sev, where in the code is this not accommodated for? the +6 is because locate return the index of the beginning of the string.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, try CHARINDEX ( expression1 , expression2 [ , start_location ] ). It does the same.

Comment: You should change your answer, not tell me in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't really think you need all these trimming and substring-ing functions.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE #t1
(
    a INT,
    b VARCHAR(64)
);
INSERT #t1 SELECT 1, '[CID]: 267 [MID]: 319A [Name]: RJR'
UNION ALL  SELECT 2, '[CID]: 26232 [MID]: 229dd5A [Name]: RJ'
UNION ALL  SELECT 3, 'Garbage that will not match';

CREATE TABLE #t2
(
    c INT,
    d VARCHAR(32)
);
INSERT #t2 SELECT 4, '319A'
UNION ALL  SELECT 5, '229dd5A'
UNION ALL  SELECT 6, 'NO MATCH';

SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t2.d
  FROM #t1 AS t1 
  INNER JOIN #t2 AS t2
  ON t1.b LIKE '%`[MID`]: ' + t2.d + ' %' ESCAPE '`'

GO
DROP TABLE #t1, #t2;
```

If you have no idea how many spaces might be between `[MID]:` and the start of your value, or the end of your value and the start of the next `[`, and assuming there are no spaces in the values you want to match, you could use:

```
  ON REPLACE(t1.b, ' ', '') LIKE '%`[MID`]:' + t2.d + '`[%' ESCAPE '`'
```